# How to use many arrays object in if-else statements

Tags: java, arrays

It is difficult to explain about my problem, I am writing code below.

My program is like Login page with just username. I have stored Usernames as String a (As String Array). With Input as Username, and using if else statement to determine whether the Username is true or not. So how can I write code in if ( ).

I tried using

```
if(b.equal(a[0])
```

```
if(b.equal(a[1])
```

```
if(b.equal(a[2])
```

Here it only takes 0th object from array, instead I want to include all objects from single array "a" to check in if statement.

I want

```
if(b.equal(Whole Objects from single array to be used at once))
```

The problem is difficult to explain 

Here is the code below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = {"JohnS", "SahilT", "VectorSingh"};
    String b;
    Scanner sc;

    sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    b = sc.nextLine();

    if (b.equals(a[0])) {
        System.out.println("You are welcome");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("You can't access");
}}
```

Comment: *`but Is there any way without using for`*  Yes.  But you rejected it as too difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please declare and initialize your variables at the same time (when possible). As to your question, you need to *iterate* the array and check if any of the values match. You can do so by iterating explicitly, or by streaming it and testing if any of the entries match `b`. Like,

```
String[] a = { "JohnS", "SahilT", "VectorSingh" };
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String b = sc.nextLine();
if (Arrays.stream(a).anyMatch(b::equals)) {
    System.out.println("You are welcome");
} else {
    System.out.println("You can't access");
}
```

Or iterating explicitly, like

```
String[] a = { "JohnS", "SahilT", "VectorSingh" };
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String b = sc.nextLine();
boolean found = false;
for (String s : a) {
    if (s.equals(b)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found) {
    System.out.println("You are welcome");
} else {
    System.out.println("You can't access");
}
```

Comment: I got it, but Is there any way without using for

Comment: @AmeyKurade Yes (by hiding the iterating and streaming the array, but that just *hides it*). Or using a `while`. Or a `do-while`. Or recursion. Your question is actually "how do I check if any value in the array matches the user supplied value"; and that requires checking the values in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put all names into `Set` as lowercase (in case you want to support case insensitivity).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> names = Set.of("johns", "sahilt", "bectorsingh");
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = scan.nextLine();

    if (names.contains(name.toLowerCase()))
        System.out.println("You are welcome");
    else
        System.out.println("You can't access");
}
```

In case you have to use arrays, you have to manually scann all elements in the array and check it.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = { "JohnS", "SahilT", "VectorSingh" };

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = scan.nextLine();

    if (isExist(name, names))
        System.out.println("You are welcome");
    else
        System.out.println("You can't access");
}

private static boolean isExist(String name, String[] names) {
    for(String n : names)
        if(n.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            return true;
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: This way is too difficult

Comment: Snippet with `Set` gives you the best performance - `O(1)`!

Comment: I will try this too

Comment: @OlegCherednik Careful. With a small number of elements (like 3) the constants involved in building a `Set` probably offset the cost of scanning the array. If there were dozens (or thousands) of names, a `Set` would probably be best.

Comment: I will use this in different projects in future

Comment: @AmeyKurade *`This is too difficult`.*  Why do you say that?  How can it be more difficult than using `streams` comparatively speaking? Instead of iterating over an array, you just check to see if it contains the `userName`.   And if usernames are case sensitive, then you don't need to do anything special with the case.  Just make certain you enter the userName correctly.   For a typical lookup of dozens of names I would definitely use a set for this as it is simpler.  Imo, this is clearly the best way.

Comment: @OlegCherednik  You may want to consider  `String message = userNames.contains(b) ? "You are welcome" : "You can't access";`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  I disagree.  Streams has significant overhead compared to a simple for loop.  Consider the intent of the problem.  Building a `set` occurs a single time to store the users which can be updated as needed by adding new users.  But for each check of a  `username` you are invoking a streams construct.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch this is your code, I am just giving you one of the way. But, do not offer your code to job interview to FAANG. You fail it then.

Comment: @WJS That is why I gave two distinct answers. The second of which was a simple `for` loop. There are definitely edge cases where a `for` loop over the array will outperform the O(1) set operations. That was my only point with my comment.

Comment: @OlegCherednik Yeah. Now you tell me. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it with simple method using foreach

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = { "JohnS", "SahilT", "VectorSingh" };
        String b;
        Scanner sc;
        boolean isCheck = false;

        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        b = sc.nextLine();
        
        sc.close();

        for (String item : a) {
            if (b.equals(item)) {
                isCheck = true;
                System.out.println("You are welcome");
                break;
            } 
        }

        if (!isCheck) {
            System.out.println("You can't access");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The else part is also printing

Comment: I fixed the answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to check the given user input is having access or not, try to do this with the below approach(s):

**Approach 1:**

***Logic:***

Here you can use simple `for` loop to iterate over the array and find the given input is present in the array or not and once it is matched, exit from the loop using `break` statement.

***Code:***

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = {"JohnS", "SahilT", "VectorSingh"};
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String b = sc.nextLine();
        for (String s : a) {
            if (s.equals(b)) {
                System.out.println("You are welcome");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You can't access");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Approach 2:**

***Logic:***

Here you can store the users in a `List` and check whether the input is present in the list or not using `.contains()` function in the list.

***Code:***

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listOfUsers = Arrays.asList("JohnS", 
                                      "SahilT", "VectorSingh");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String b = sc.nextLine();
        if(listOfUsers.contains(b)){
            System.out.println("You are welcome");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You can't access");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... using if else statement to determine whether the Username is true or not. So how can I write code in if ( ). ..."*

You can convert *a* to a *[List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)* and utilize the *[contains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))* method.

```java
if (List.of(a).contains(b))
```

If you need a case-insensitive match, you can stream the array, and utilize the *[anyMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate))* method to evaluate an *[equalsIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))* on *b*.

```java
if (Stream.of(a).anyMatch(b::equalsIgnoreCase))
```